# Foreign key not saving in child table in a One-to-many relationship

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I am developing an REST API application using spring boot and is struck up with the One to Many mapping while using mappedBy property. 
I have User class and Usermeata class, a user can have more than one usermeta.

While the program successfully save the foreign while using JoinColumn, I want to know what mistake I am committing while using mappedby.

Here is my code:

User Entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="User")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long userId;

    @Column(unique=true)
    private String username;

    @Column(unique=true)
    private String emailId; 

    private String password;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String phoneNo;
    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER,cascade=CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy="user")
//  @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
    private List<UserMeta> userMetaList=new ArrayList();




    public List<UserMeta> getUserMetaList() {
        return userMetaList;
    }

    public void setUserMetaList(List<UserMeta> userMetaList) {
        this.userMetaList = userMetaList;
    }

    public Long getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(Long userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getEmailId() {
        return emailId;
    }

    public void setEmailId(String emailId) {
        this.emailId = emailId;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getPhoneNo() {
        return phoneNo;
    }

    public void setPhoneNo(String phoneNo) {
        this.phoneNo = phoneNo;
    }


}
```

UserMeta class:

```
@Entity
public class UserMeta {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long userMetaId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
    private User user;

    private String _key;

    private String _value;

    public Long getUserMetaId() {
        return userMetaId;
    }

    public void setUserMetaId(Long userMetaId) {
        this.userMetaId = userMetaId;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public String get_key() {
        return _key;
    }

    public void set_key(String _key) {
        this._key = _key;
    }

    public String get_value() {
        return _value;
    }

    public void set_value(String _value) {
        this._value = _value;
    }

}
```

UserService.class

```
@Service
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository  userRepository;

    public User getUser(Long  userId) {
        return userRepository.getOne(userId);
    }

    public List<User> getAllUser() {
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }

    public User addUser(User user) {
        return userRepository.save(user);
    }

    public void removeUser(User user) {
        userRepository.delete(user);
    }

    public void updateUser(User user) {
        userRepository.save(user);
    }
}
```

POST request:

```
{
    "username":"myusername",
    "emailId":"myemailid@gmail.com1",
    "password":"2323@123",
    "firstName":"myfname",
    "lastName":"mlname",
    "phoneNo":"000000",
    "userMetaList":[
        {
            "_key":"api_key",
            "_value":"api_key_value"
        },
        {
            "_key":"prop1",
            "_value":"val1"
        }
        ]
}
```

Now the tables are created and updated with the values, however the column user_id in the table usermeta is always null..

Comment: Post the code which you use to save them.

Comment: This question has been asked a million times already. The user_id column is null because the `user` field of your UserMeta objects is null. It's as simple as that.

Comment: I looked up google and stackoverflow a lot of times, unfortunately nothing seemed to work (maybe I implemented in the wrong way, hence my last resort was to post the question myself.) . How do I assign user to the user field in Usermeta?

Comment: If the issue is with the user field in UserMeta object, why does the application works fine while using @JoinTable instead of mappedBy?

Comment: *How do I assign user to the user field in Usermeta*: by calling `userMeta.setuser(theOwningUser)`. *why does the application works fine while using @JoinTable instead of mappedBy*: because i that case, you have a unidirectional association, where UserMeta doesn't even have a user field, and where the owning side of the association is User.userMetaList, and not UserMeta.user. Read the documentation. It's all explained there.

Comment: Thanks I got it, this article explains everything very nicely: https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Comment: @JB Nizet Is it a naming convention to set user to usermeta object by making method addUserMeta(UserMeta usermeta) ?

Comment: No. It's just... good naming: the method adds a UserMeta, so you name the method `addUserMeta`. If the method started a car engine, you would name it `startCarEngine`.

Comment: Then how would the Spring know what it should execute this method? Does spring/hibernate execute each and every method in the Entity class?